# Ограничить доступ для редактирования передаваемой модели в PUT-методе

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода, rest, asp.net-web-api

Есть вот такая сущность:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string CategoryName { get; set; } //доступно для редактирования только пользователю «admin»
    // в реальном проекте свойств больше 
    // и среди них также есть доступные для редактирования только для admin
}
```

Необходимо на стороне сервера создать метод `PUT`, который обеспечил бы редактирование свойства `CategoryName` только для авторизованного пользователя **admin**.

**Какие практики REST существуют для реализации подобном логики?**

---

Моя реализация такова:

```
public class ProductDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] ProductDto productDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("dto");
        }

        var productId = RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();

        var userName = User.Identity.Name; //извлекаем имя авторизованного пользователя
        var isAdmin = userName == "admin";

        _productService.Update(productId, productDto, isAdmin);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}

public interface IProductService
{
    void Update(string id, ProductDto dto, bool isAdmin);
}

public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Product> _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IGenericRepository<Product> productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public void Update(string id, ProductDto dto, bool isAdmin)
    {
        if (dto == null || id == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));
        }

        product.Name = dto.Name;            
        if(isAdmin)
        {
            product.CategoryName = dto.CategoryName;
        }


        _productRepository.Update(product);
    }
}
```

1. Какими изъянами обладает данный код, учитывая то, что входе масштабирования у сущности `Product`будут появляться новые свойства, среди которых также могут быть те которые редактировать может только admin.
2. Или стоило попробовать использовать атрибуты валидации/перезагрузку PUT-метода и т.п?

Answer (score 1):

Привязывать функционал к имени пользователя не лучшее решение в подобных ситуациях. Для разграничения доступа к функционалу есть специальные средства под названием "роли". Каждому зарегистрированному пользователю можно добавить одну или несколько ролей описывающих его права в системе.

Исходя из этого следует второе правило, это разделение прав доступа к функционалу на отдельные методы - "action". В вашем случае первый метод будет вызывать обновление ограниченное количество полей модели, второй метод будет обновлять расширенные поля модели. Конечно для этого придется с клиента вызывать разные методы в зависимости от роли пользователя и в случае нехватки уровня доступа клиентский метод возвратит вменяемую ошибку (403)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test"), Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut, Route("{id}")]
    public void PutAll(int id, [FromBody]BaseModelDto model)
    {

    }

    [HttpPut, Route("{id}/admin"), Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public void PutAdmin(int id, [FromBody]ModelDto model)
    {

    }
}
```

Что такое роли и как с ними работать можно почитать тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/231807/

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы PUT-запрос у юзера и админа был одинаков, к примеру запрос на изменение продукта с id=1: `api/products/1`. Можно ли добиться такого или что говорит на этот счет REST?

Comment: @adamshakhabov можно перенести логику разделения прав доступа в проверку модели, т.е. релизовать свой атрибут проверки для свойства модели где вы можете задать ограничения на допустимые значения в зависимости от роли назначенной пользователю